# Finding rows based on two different values in another column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by

I have a dataset where I have two columns of `ID` and  `Category`.
An `ID` may have more than one unique **category**. My goal is to identify and count those **IDs** that have two categories: `a & b`

This is a snapshot of the dataset:

```
ID <- c(1,2,1,3,1,2,3,4,5,4,5)
category <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "c")

   ID category
1   1        a
2   2        a
3   1        b
4   3        a
5   1        c
6   2        a
7   3        b
8   4        b
9   5        c
10  4        d
11  5        c
```

In this example, **IDs** `1 & 3` have categories `a & b`.
So, I need to identify such IDs and also count the total number of such IDs.
I truly appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(all(c("a", "b") %in% category)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   distinct(ID)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 1
     ID
  <dbl>
1     1
2     3
```